# How to click a link that will execute but not redirect.

Tags: javascript, jquery, preventdefault

I have a few products in a mySQL database whose links are being retrieved in my script with $producturl. These url's actually add the product to the cart (http://www.example.com/cart/?add-to-cart=1127). I am trying to create a script that will allow the user to add products to the cart but NOT redirect them, just execute the link so the user stays on the same page.

I am using preventDefault and stopPropgation but it is not working. The alert shows up but the link itself is not executing when I view my cart later the product is not there. Any help?

```
<?php $producturl = ProductURL::find(array('Product'=>$tube1->Tube1));
if($producturl[0]->URL!=NULL){  
echo '<span id="shop">Add Cart NoRedirect</span>';
}
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('click', '#shop', function (event) {
 $.post( '<?php echo $producturl[0]->URL; ?>' );
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
alert('Product has been added to cart');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried `return false;` instead of `preventDefault();` ?

Comment: i think alert will stop the return function() . u just remove the alert and check it .. if you want alert use some jquery pop up,

Comment: I replaced return false but it didn't work (checking the cart after clicking and it says nothing in cart). I also removed the alert function to check manually after.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your HTML anchor link:

```
<a id='link1' href="http://www.google.com">Link</a>
```

The jQuery JS required (don't forget to put this inside a DOM ready function):

```
// Act on clicks to a elements
$("#link1").on('click', function(e) {
    // prevent the default action, in this case the following of a link
    e.preventDefault();
    // capture the href attribute of the a element
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    // perform a get request using ajax to the captured href value
    $.get(url, function() {
        // success
    });
});
```

This demonstrates all the principles required to implement your function.

The page in question and the URL POSTed to must be on the same subdomain, or cross origin resource sharing must be appropriately enabled on the server otherwise the request will fail due to cross domain restrictions.

Comment: I revised my code per your suggestion and put the jQuery click function within a document ready function. Clicking the link several times and then going to my cart I still see 'nothing in cart'. Any additional suggestions?

edit: I also put the hard link into the href just to demo-test (ie: /cart/?add-to-cart=1127)

Comment: Firstly ensure that you target the correct links with the select in line 2. Next, you may need to use POST rather than GET for the Ajax section. If that doesn't help then I'm going to need to see a working example.

Comment: I added an alert immediately after the var url = $(this) and it receives the correct URL. I also revised the GET to `$.post(url, function (resp) {
    alert("Product added to cart"); });` It does not seem to be processing the last line because I am not getting an alert. Did I create the post wrong?

Comment: Is the page in question on the same subdomain as the URL you are POSTing to? Cross domain restrictions apply.

Comment: My code was not in the same subdomain. CDR was the problem you are correct thank you.

Comment: Glad that worked for you. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Apologies I meant to tick but forgot. Thanks!

Comment: It still hasn't been ticked :)

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
'<a href="#" id="shop">Add Cart NoRedirect</a>'
```

or

```
'<a href="javascript: return false;" id="shop">Add Cart NoRedirect</a>'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an image, a button, a div or a text decorated as link instead of a link.

Answer (score 0):

```
'<a href="javascript: void(0);" id="shop">Add Cart NoRedirect</a>'
```